# bytes32 same length hex strings cost different gas why?

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, hash, bytes32

I can not understand the difference in gas for the following problem. I generated a sha256 hash value and the output i chose to be lowercase hexadecimal. So the output value is hexadecimal string of 64 characters.Then i saved this value to a bytes32 variable inside a smart contract. The smart contract's code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Project {
    bytes32 public value;

    function addValue(bytes32 val) public {
        value = val;
    }
}
```

Using remix, I noticed that the operation to add a value cost 43629 for some values and other 43693. So the difference is 64 gas. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? I tested many values and the difference was 64 gas, was it random? I also tested to store it as string. Then the cost was constant for all inputs, maybe because the values have the same length as i said the inputs values have 64 characters.

Comment: Just a guess, but is the difference how many bytes are 0 in the input?

Comment: @smarx I tested it for two inputs that both have seven zeros. The one costed 43629 and the other 64 gas more so 43693 so i don't think the zeros matter. But nice i idea i haven't thought to check it before you notice it.

Comment: To clarify, you're counting the number of complete bytes that are 0s, not just the total number of 0s that occur in the hexadecimal string? (E.g. 0x102030 has no zero bytes, but 0x100020 has one zero byte.)

Comment: @smarx ok so i did it wrong i counted the number of zeros, silly me.. So you mean i should convert it to binary and then i should make  teams of consecutive 8 bits and see if a "team" has all bits 0? sorry if my english are not good

Comment: Well, hexadecimal is fine. Every two hexadecimal characters is a single byte. If you would just share the values you're testing here, this would be much easier.

Comment: @smarx for example a value that cost 43629 is "0x44c6a374366f345cec0fa7d98eddf8185a533d4f3922c9c9397c38e8a8f526e2" and the other with 64 less gas is "0xd5bf2cb491dd63f800373f16ab0fc486ffe040923587c00adcead3dc4a4544b6". So the consecutive zeros in the second input are the problem?

Comment: @smarx Bravo! You were right! Now i get it i split it in teams of consecutive two so i get a byte. then i see how many teams are only zeros. Yes the second string has one team of zeros so cost 64 less. Then i insert this one "0x44c6a374366f345cec0fa7d98eddf8185a533d4f3922c9c9397c38e8a8f50000" which is the first string with 4 zeros at the end. So 2 bytes zero and it costed 120 less. Thank you!!!

Comment: It should have cost 128 less than a value that had no zeros. See my answer for a little more detail.

Comment: @smarx i know it is off topic but do you know by any chance how many zero bytes may occur in an output of sha256? Yes right 128 !

Comment: The output of sha256 is 256 bits, which is 32 bytes. So there can be up to 32 zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the yellow paper](http://yellowpaper.io/):

> Gtxdatazero 4 Paid for every zero byte of data or code for a transaction.
>
> Gtxdatanonzero 68 Paid for every non-zero byte of data or code for a transaction

So if you replace a non-zero with a zero in your transaction data, you'll reduce the cost by 64 (68-4).

Note that *consecutive* 0s don't necessarily matter, just if they represent a full byte. It's easier to see if you separate bytes: `d5 bf 2c b4 91 dd 63 f8 00 37 3f 16 ab 0f c4 86 ff e0 40 92 35 87 c0 0a dc ea d3 dc 4a 45 44 b6`. So the second value you mentioned in your comment has exactly one zero byte.